# GRDB Sync with nested array

Tags: json, swift, sqlite, grdb

I am using GRDB to sync my JSON payload to SQLite however I am encountering an error whenever I have an array of other items within the main payload.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

My JSON is:

```
{ "newsData": [
  {
    "newsID" : 6,
    "content" : "Test",
    "author" : "Test Author",
    "published" : 1,
    "title" : "Test news",
    "dateAdded" : "2015-12-18 11:33:15",
    "imagePath" : null,
    "newsCategoryData" : [

    ],
    "shortDescription" : "Test",
    "newsTagData" : [

    ],
    "lastModified" : null
  },
```

as you can see I have newsCategoryData and newsTagData as arrays. The sync is:

```
 do {
   let jsonString =
      "{ \"newsData\": " +
        "\(responseJSON["newsData"]) " +
      "}"
    try dbQueue.inTransaction { db in
      try self.synchronizeNewsWithJSON(jsonString, inDatabase: db)
      return .Commit
    }
}
```

The issue is newsCategoryData and newsTagData because if I remove those from the payload everything syncs correctly. Is it possible to ignore these 2 items when performing a sync as I will sync these 2 at a later stage.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
func synchronizeNewsWithJSON(jsonString: String, inDatabase db: Database) throws {
    let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

    func jsonNewsID(jsonNews: NSDictionary) -> Int64 {
        return (jsonNews["newsID"] as! NSNumber).longLongValue
    }

    let jsonNews = (json["newsData"] as! [NSDictionary]).sort {
        return jsonNewsID($0) < jsonNewsID($1)
    }

    let news = NewsModel.fetchAll(db, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY newsID")

    for mergeStep in sortedMerge(
        left: news,
        right: jsonNews,
        leftKey: { $0.newsID! },
        rightKey: jsonNewsID)
    {
        switch mergeStep {
        case .Left(let news):
            try news.delete(db)

        case .Right(let jsonNews):
            let row = Row(dictionary: jsonNews)!
            let news = NewsModel(row: row)
            try news.insert(db)

        case .Common(let news, let jsonNews):
            news.updateFromJSON(jsonNews)
            try news.update(db)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the implementation of synchronizeNewsWithJSON it's difficult to help you, since it looks like the application crashes inside this method.

Comment: @GwendalRoué - Thanks, I have added the method

Comment: Something is wrong with your question. You don't give the necessary information. For example, you say that when you remove some piece of information from the JSON data, your apps stops crashing. And yet nowhere in your question can we see where and how this JSON is consumed, nowhere can we see where exactly your program is crashing. Please enhance drastically your question.

Comment: I don't know what further information I can give. If the JSON payload has a nested array i.e. newsCategoryData and newsTagData the sync fails as I imagine the sync is trying to sync these 2 items as well. But if I remove those to arrays from the payload, sync works perfectly. If you are unsure don't worry, I will amend my JSON to have these 2 items outside of the newsData.